# busybox: httpd: config error 'E404:index.html' in 'httpd.conf'

Tags: busybox

I am trying to add an error page to busybox but I keep running in:

```
httpd: config error 'E404:index.html' in 'httpd.conf'
```

This is the starting point: https://github.com/lipanski/docker-static-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue in [lipanski/docker-static-website:2.1.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/lipanski/docker-static-website/tags) and as long as you set a `httpd.conf` in your project root, it should work fine.

As a general explanation, BusyBox httpd only processes the error directives for the main configuration file and rejects it anywhere else. The main configuration file is the one specified via the `-c` argument, as in `httpd -c httpd.conf`.

For more details, check their [parse_conf implementation](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c).